# Calculate score in a game based on time passed

Tags: game-theory

I'm creating a game which would give the player points based on time they needed to solve a puzzle. The faster they complete it, the more points they get. I need a formula which would calculate such score. "t" should be the total completion time in seconds, "x" should define the decrease in points per second. The base score should be 10000 and decrease gradually to 0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just $\max(10000-t \cdot x,0)$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov how can I make each additional second take less points away than the previous one?

Comment: Is there an earliest time at which you want the score to be $0$?

Comment: @paw88789 let's say 7200 sec

Comment: @Ernest P W : By making the decrease $x$ a decreasing function of time. But that leaves a lot of room for what kind of dependency you want. I feel this is not a math question, but a question of game design.

Comment: One relatively straightforward function where the decrement falls off linearly is $f(t) = \frac{10000(T-t)^2}{T^2}$ for $0 \leq t \leq T$, $f(t) = 0$ for $t > T$, where $T$ is the time limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the specification:

- $f(t) = 0 ~: t \geq 7200.$
- Else,  $~\displaystyle f(t) = \frac{10000}{10000^{(t/7200)}}.$

Then,

$$f(0) = \frac{10000}{10000^{(0)}}  = \frac{10000}{1}$$

and, as $(t)$ approaches $(7200)$, $f(t)$ will approach

$$\frac{10000}{10000^{\left(\frac{7200}{7200}\right)}} = \frac{10000}{10000^{(1)}} = 1.$$

---

**Addendum**
As Brian Tung indicated in the comment following this answer, the function is not continuous, as $t$ approaches $7200$.

A more complicated version of the function, which would provide continuity is

- $f(t) = 0 ~: t \geq 7200.$
- Else,  $~\displaystyle f(t) = -1 + \frac{10001}{10001^{(t/7200)}}.$

Then,

$$f(0) = -1 + \frac{10001}{10001^{(0)}}  = -1 + \frac{10001}{1}$$

and, as $(t)$ approaches $(7200)$, $f(t)$ will approach

$$-1 + \frac{10001}{10001^{\left(\frac{7200}{7200}\right)}} = -1 + \frac{10001}{10001^{(1)}} = 0.$$

Comment: It might be nice to make the function continuous at $t = 7200$.

Comment: @BrianTung Agreed.  However, when I looked at that, it seemed that the adjustment needed was to deduct $(1)$ from the current $f(t)$ expression.  This would have the expression going from $9999$ to $(0)$.  Then, the 2nd adjustment needed would be to utilize the number $(10001)$ instead of $(10000)$.  However, given the OP's (i.e. Original Poster's) lack of familiarity with the Math, I judged this to be too complicated for him to have to digest.  So, I favored simplicity over continuity.

Comment: Understood! Though I suspect whatever is easy to code will be fine with the OP.

Comment: @BrianTung See my Addendum.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you another choice (and expanding on my comment), a **parabola** has the nice feature that the decrement will fall off linearly over time. We want a parabola that starts at $10000$ at $t = 0$, then drops off and skims to the $x$ axis at $t = T$, where $T$ is the time limit. The expression is

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{10000(T-t)^2}{T^2} & 0 \leq t \leq 7200 \\
0 & t > 7200
\end{cases}
$$

For example, for $T = 7200$, as given in your comment, we have a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Either a linear falloff (as here) or an exponential falloff (as in user2661923's answer) is a reasonable choice. There are, of course, (infinitely) many others, but simplicity is key. :-)